# Finding range of $\sin^{20}(\theta)+\cos^{30}(\theta)$.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

We have to find the range of 
$$\sin^{20}(\theta)+\cos^{30}(\theta)$$

I have found the upper limit which is $1$.

I am a high school student and we were taught to convert functions into a simpler function to calculate the range.

I would like to know what kind of method is used in these types of problems. 
[image]
Here is a graph to clear some confusions in comments

Comment: is there any restriction on the domain?

Comment: Also, note that the lower bound is $0.$

Comment: @SaketGurjar, no there is no bound

Comment: @SahibaArora, I know the bound is 0(using a graph), how to prove it

Comment: The lower bound is certainly not zero.  Both terms are squares, so the sum can only be zero if both are equal to zero, which does not happen.

Comment: @nate, Open at 0, tends to 0

Comment: @Nate I certainly didn't claim that $0$ was attained.

Comment: Well I'd say that calling it "the lower bound" as opposed to "a lower bound" suggests it is optimal,  but this is more of an issue of ambiguous language than mathematics.

Comment: And no Arjun, it does not tend to zero.  The actual minimum value is approximately .0004329.

Comment: @nate, can you please share how you reached this conclusion?

Comment: I mean I knew it couldn't be zero for the reason above. I also knew it must obtain a minimum value somewhere between 0 and $\pi/2$ because it is periodic and continuous. Then I just looked for the minimum numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea:

$$\sin^{20}\theta +\cos^{30}\theta$$

$$\sin^{20}\theta +(1-\sin^2\theta)^{15}$$

Put $\sin^2\theta =t$. Notice that $t \in [0,1]$ for no restriction on the domain.

Now $$f(t) = t^{10} +(1-t)^{15} \ \ \forall \ \ t \in [0,1] $$

$f(x)$ is continuous, so the extremum will occur at boundary points or where the derivative is $0$.

$$f(1) = 1$$

$$f(0) = 1$$

$$f'(t) = 10t^9-15(1-t)^{14}$$

Now you just wish you have a calculator or Wolfram Alpha to calculate the zero of this .

It comes out to be : $$t=0.43289180011435746401...$$

The value of $f(t)$ at this $t$ is $\approx 0.000432928$

So the range is :

$$f(t) \in [\approx 0.000432928, 1] $$

[Wolfram Alpha link to calculation of point of Minima.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28x%5E9%29%2F3%20%3D%281-x%29%5E14)

I noticed someone said that the lower bound tends to $0$. This is clearly not the case.

Zoomed-in image of the graph in the question at point of minima (It clearly does not approach zero.)

[image]

Comment: Bro, you know India we are not allowed calcy in exams!

Comment: @SaketGurjar I didn't mean "the" lower bound, more like "a" lower bound.

Comment: The lower bound is attained at the critical point (so the range is a closed interval).

Comment: @Karl thanks for pointing that out. Edit on the way.

Comment: @ArjunRana I know calcy is not allowed, so the chances of this coming in an actual exam is quite low.....how else do you suggest calculating that monstrosity of a polynomial.

Comment: Teachers at fitjee are gods, they did in few minutes in online class but due to connectivity issues I missed it completely

Comment: Did they solve the actual value or just "something close to zero"?....If they solved the exact value, they must be gods.....or there is a neat closed form for that value obtained from another method.

Comment: @ArjunRana you can find out that the minima is "not zero but more than it" without calculator...so if you are practising for JEE, you can check which option is closest to the actual interval.

Comment: Surely, playing with a, b, c, d is something indians excel at

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the derivative of this function, and look for where it is zero. This will correspond to the local extremes.